# Dependancy not satisfiable while installing sql query browser

Tags: software-installation

I have tried to install Query Browser for Ubuntu, but there is a error called

> "Dependency is Not satisfiable: libmysqlclient16(>=5.1.50-1)"

but my friends OS is supported to same software.how should i install this software.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to (re)install mysql-5.1.

Type the following into terminal and enter your password when prompted:

`sudo apt-get update`

`sudo apt-get install mysql-5.1`